# Javascript tutorial, please explain

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie learning Javascript. In the following tutorial, I don`t understand

- why value is initially set to null
- if the value entered is 2, for example, how does the program know to display "You`re an embarassment" and not redisplay the initial question "What is the value of 2 + 2"?

The question/prompt is triggered when value != 4 so I would expect an answer of 2 to retrigger to question/prompt, but instead the program displays the message "You`re an embarassment".

Can anyone explain?

```
var value = null;
while (value != "4") {
  value = prompt("You! What is the value of 2 + 2?", "");
  if (value == "4")
    alert("You must be a genius or something.");
  else if (value == "3" || value == "5")
    alert("Almost!");
  else
    alert("You're an embarrassment.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The value is initially set to null so that when the while loop checks to verify it should be started, the loop will return true. I.E. value does not equal "4", it equals null. 
You could also set value to anything other than 4.

b)the value you enter into the dialog box will be what value is set to, so since value does not equal 3, 4, or 5 it falls into the all other scenarios with else.

Comment: but if you enter 2 into the dialogue box, value != 4 is still true, so why doesn`t it retrigger the question What is the value of 2 +2?

Comment: actually, it retriggers the question if you enter "2" but only after it displays the alert "You`re an embarassment." how does it know to display the alert "You`re an embarassmetn* before it retriggers the question?  Entering "2" should trigger both at the same time, so how does the program know the correct order?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. 
But the way it works is since value is not 4 it enters the while loop, then it prompts, then it continues through the if\else control structure to find if it needs to continue if value does not equal 4 the loop continues and you receive the prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

The `value != 4` is the condition for the `while` loop to process. As long as `value` does not equal (`!=`) 4, then it will continue prompting.

Once inside the while loop, it gets you to enter a number.
Then the number is checked (the `if-else if-else`) and does line following beneath it. If something other than 4 is entered, such as 2, `value` does not equal 4 and will prompt you to enter a number again.

This will continue until you enter 4.

I've added some comments (and braces) to the code sample, hopefully it will help clarify things...

```
var value = null;
while (value != "4") {//While value is not 4 do the following code
  value = prompt("You! What is the value of 2 + 2?", "");//Get a value from the user
  if (value == "4"){//If value equals 4, then do the following
    alert("You must be a genius or something.");
  }//end of if block
  else if (value == "3" || value == "5"){//If value is equal to 3 or 5 then d0
    alert("Almost!");
  }//end of else-if block
  else{//If value is something we haven't explicitly checked for, then do this
    alert("You're an embarrassment.");
  }//end of else block
}//End of while loop
```

EDIT - My response to the comment was too long
This block of code works as follows:
`var value = null` Create a variable named value and set it equal to null
`while(value != 4){...whileblock...}` (ignoring the code inside the while loop) While value is not equal to 4, then execute the `whileblock` code
Once we are inside the while loop (which will happen since `null` does not equal `4`) we start operating on the additional code
`value = prompt("...");` Ask the user to input something

```
if(value=="4"){...ifblock...}
else if(value=="3" || value=="5"){...ifelseblock...}
else{...elseblock...}
```

This block operates as: If value is equal to 4, do the `ifblock` of code. If my value is not equal to 4, then check the next component, which is `if(value=="3"||value=="5")`. This says, If my value is 3, or if my value is 5, then do the code in `ifelseblock`. If we didn't do `ifelseblock` then go to the next component, which is the `else` part. That says, whatever is in value doesn't matter, we made it this far down, so go ahead and run `elseblock`. (Of course, replaced each of those `*block` pieces with the corresponding code)
Now that it is done, the while loop returns to the top to see if we should continue executing the `whileblock` code. So it checks to see if value does not equal 4. If value equals 4, it won't run the loop again. If value is something other than 4, it will run all, that code again, asking for a prompt, doing the comparisons and displaying the appropriate alert box.

I hope all that helps clear it up some.

Comment: thanks, if you run the program, you will see that, if you enter "2", it will first display "You`re an embarassment" and then ask the question again after you click o.k., How does it know which order to display the alerts? Why does it display "You`re an embarassment" before it asks the question again?  the answer "2" should retrigger the question at the same time that it triggers "You`re an embarassment" so how does the program know the right order?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you type in 4, it will say "You must be a genius or something.". If you type 3 or 5, it will say "Almost!" Anything else it will say "You're an embarrassment"

Comment: Good job answering the question. /sarcasm

Comment: @Kranu 'how does the program know to display "You`re an embarassment"'

Comment: Yeah. If someone asks "How does a printer print?" Your answer would be: the printer takes in data from USB or network and puts it out on paper.